# How does one implement different token prices at different rounds (or times in the contract) for an ICO?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ico

I am a new programmer, here is my code. Any useful information and tips are appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Token {

    /// @return total amount of tokens
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply) {}

    /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
    /// @return The balance
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    /// @param _from The address of the sender
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_addr` to spend `_value` tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @param _value The amount of wei to be approved for transfer
    /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {}

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}

contract StandardToken is Token {

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
        //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
        //Replace the if with this one instead.
        //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
        //if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
      return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
}

contract FLOCK is StandardToken { // CHANGE THIS. Update the contract name.

    /* Public variables of the token */

    /*
    NOTE:
    The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
    They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
    Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
    */
    string public name;                   // Token Name
    uint8 public decimals;                // How many decimals to show. To be standard complicant keep it 18
    string public symbol;                 // An identifier: eg SBX, XPR etc..
    string public version = 'H1.0'; 
    uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy;     // How many units of your coin can be bought by 1 ETH?
    uint256 public totalEthInWei;         // WEI is the smallest unit of ETH (the equivalent of cent in USD or satoshi in BTC). We'll store the total ETH raised via our ICO here.  
    address public fundsWallet;           // Where should the raised ETH go?

    // This is a constructor function 
    // which means the following function name has to match the contract name declared above
    function FLOCK() {
        balances[msg.sender] = 10000000000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens. This is set to 1000 for example. If you want your initial tokens to be X and your decimal is 5, set this value to X * 100000. (CHANGE THIS)
        totalSupply = 10000000000;                        // Update total supply (1000 for example) (CHANGE THIS)
        name = "FLOCK";                                   // Set the name for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        decimals = 0;                                               // Amount of decimals for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        symbol = "FLK";                                             // Set the symbol for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        unitsOneEthCanBuy = 50000;                                      // Set the price of your token for the ICO (CHANGE THIS)
        fundsWallet = msg.sender;                                    // The owner of the contract gets ETH
    }

    function() payable{
        totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value;
        uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy;
        require(balances[fundsWallet] >= amount);

        balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;

        Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, amount); // Broadcast a message to the blockchain

        //Transfer ether to fundsWallet
        fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);                               
    }

    /* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
        //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
        //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
        if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { throw; }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here are example of two pricing contracts https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/MilestonePricing.sol and https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/EthTranchePricing.sol

Answer (score 1):

## Function to determine rate

Add code to return different values for the `unitsOneEthCanBuy` based on the block timestamp.

### Example

```
uint created = block.timestamp;
uint round_two = created + 7 days;
uint round_three = round_two + 30 days;
uint end = round_three + 30 days;

/// @notice Gets the conversion rate for ETH purchases.
/// @return Amount of tokens per ETH paid.
function unitsOneEthCanBuy() public view returns (uint _units) {
    if (block.timestamp > end) {
        return 0; // Sale has ended
    } else if (block.timestamp > round_three) {
        return 100000; // Round 3 price
    } else if (block.timestamp > round_two) {
        return 75000; // Round 2 price
    }
    return 50000; // Round 1 price
}
```

Then you would remove:

```
uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy;
```

And everywhere you use `unitsOneEthCanBuy`, use `unitsOneEthCanBuy()` instead.

## Other potential issues

### Overflow checking

You have very little code doing overflow checking in the transfer functions, you should probably use a common library like [SafeMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) to do the mathematical operations safely.

#### Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

/// @title An example contract demonstrating using safe math operations
contract Example {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    /// @notice Adds two numbers together safely
    /// @param a The first number
    /// @param b The second number
    function addTogether(uint a, uint b) returns (uint) {
        return a.add(b);
    }
}
```

### ERC223 safety

Consider checking for contracts as transfer destinations and calling the tokenFallback method to make sure it's safe to transfer. This will stop your coins getting lost.

#### Example:

This is not enough to make your contract ERC223 compliant, but it's enough to ensure your tokens don't get lost

Add the following to your `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions just before you emit the Transfer events:

```
if (isContract(_to)) {
    iReceiver receiver = iReceiver(_to);
    receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, empty);
}
```

Then add a function called isContract to your contract:

```
function isContract(address _addr) private view returns (bool _is_contract) {
    uint length;
    assembly {
        length := extcodesize(_addr)
    }
    return (length>0);
}
```

And add an interface called `iReceiver` to above your contracts:

```
interface iReceiver {
    function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data) external;
}
```

Comment: Hey if I could send you my revised code could you tell me if it looks better? I’d be glad to send you some ether for your time and help.

Comment: I appreciate your help, norganna.

Comment: Sure, post a link, I'm happy to review your final solution for upvotes :)

Comment: http://collabedit.com/8btn8

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer. If not let me know so I can further assist.